# Clarification on a userstory toggle

Tags: azure-devops

I'm not sure what it means when the toggle Requires QA is set to False
can someone explain it to me would be much appreciated.
[image]
I'm not sure if its bad thing or a good thing for me as a QA

Answer (score 0):

The **`Boolean`** type "**Requires QA**" is not a built-in field of work item process in Azure DevOps. It is a customized field created and added by a user within your Azure DevOps organization.

By default, only the users who are the PCA (**Project Collection Administrators**, including Organization Owner) of the organization have the permissions to edit/customize the work item process.

[image]

---

For your case, I recommended you try to contact the PCA of your organization to get more detailed clarifications about the actual purpose of the "**Requires QA**" field.

---